# Show compiler calls to tools like as, ar, ld or determine equivalent calls

Tags: c++, compilation, ld

Is there a way to get gcc, icc, or clang to show what they're doing as an equivalent series of shell commands? In particular, I'd like to see everything that comes after compiling to assembly.

I'm not sure if it makes sense to ask for the exact shell commands being used or if the tools are used through APIs. Still, there should be an equivalent sequence of shell commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With clang:

```
[9:49am][wlynch@apple /tmp] /opt/llvm/3.4/bin/clang++ -### foo.cc 
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
 "/opt/llvm/3.4/bin/clang" "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-disable-free" "-disable-llvm-verifier" "-main-file-name" "foo.cc" "-mrelocation-model" "static" "-mdisable-fp-elim" "-fmath-errno" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" "-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-target-linker-version" "2.20.51.0.2" "-resource-dir" "/opt/llvm/3.4/bin/../lib/clang/3.4" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/x86_64-redhat-linux" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/backward" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/x86_64-redhat-linux/c++/4.4.7" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/local/include" "-internal-isystem" "/opt/llvm/3.4/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/usr/include" "-fdeprecated-macro" "-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/tmp" "-ferror-limit" "19" "-fmessage-length" "182" "-mstackrealign" "-fobjc-runtime=gcc" "-fcxx-exceptions" "-fexceptions" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-fcolor-diagnostics" "-vectorize-slp" "-o" "/tmp/foo-048f22.o" "-x" "c++" "foo.cc"
 "/usr/bin/ld" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-m" "elf_x86_64" "-dynamic-linker" "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" "-o" "a.out" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtbegin.o" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64" "-L/lib/../lib64" "-L/usr/lib/../lib64" "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../.." "-L/lib" "-L/usr/lib" "/tmp/foo-048f22.o" "-lstdc++" "-lm" "-lgcc_s" "-lgcc" "-lc" "-lgcc_s" "-lgcc" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtend.o" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crtn.o"
```